# Is there any way to use Gradle to build the iOS Client Libraries for App Engine

Tags: ios, xcode, google-app-engine, gradle, google-cloud-endpoints

Is there any way to use Gradle to build the iOS Client Libraries for App Engine? I currently have an Android App and a Cloud Endpoint Module being built with Android studio.

For iOS, I will use Xcode and its Gradle [plugin](http://openbakery.org/gradle.php). How can I automate the client library generation so `gradle iosapp:build` will fully build the iOS app with those libraries, even if the backend changes? Is this possible?